# Complex search with where clause built based on user input - how to index for performance?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing, query-optimization

Using Oracle 11G.

Running the following SQL, that is built based on the inputs from a search prompt screen shown to the users:

```
select ibf_unitnumber, ibf_locationnumber, ibf_repairingsubcenternum, 
ibf_repairingdistrictnum, ibf_customernumber, process_instance_id, 
ibf_repairdate, ibf_ronumber, ibf_customername, BF_WORKTYPE, 
ibf_districtnumber, status, ibf_jobtype,ibf_pmvalidationform_req, 
ibf_ecmform_req 
from FIELD_CT 
WHERE 
trim(ibf_unitnumber) in (#unitNumberList[]#)
AND trim(IBF_CUSTOMERNUMBER)=#customerNumber#
AND trim(IBF_CUSTOMERNAME)=#customerName#
AND trim(IBF_DISTRICTNUMBER)=#locationDist#
AND trim(IBF_LOCATIONNUMBER)=#locationSubcenter#
AND trim(IBF_REPAIRINGDISTRICTNUM)=#repairLocationDist#
AND trim(IBF_REPAIRINGSUBCENTERNUM)=#repairLocationSubCenter#
AND trim(IBF_RONUMBER)=#repairOrderNumber#
AND trim(BF_WORKTYPE)=#docTypeVal#
AND IBF_REPAIRDATE >= #repairStartDt# AND IBF_REPAIRDATE <= #repairEndDt#
AND trim(IBF_JOBTYPE)=#jobTypeVal#
AND trim(IBF_ECMFORM_REQ)=#ecmFormReq#
AND trim(IBF_PMVALIDATIONFORM_REQ)=#pmValidationReq# 
AND trim(status) in ("PI_COMPLETED","PI_ACTIVATED")
```

there will be an AND between those when they are all built based on user input.  ##s used to indicate the substitution of the user input value.

so, if the user puts in a unit# of 1234567 and a repair order number of RO54321 on the prompt, then only these lines would be included and the actual SQL where clause built and run would be:

WHERE 
trim(ibf_unitnumber) in (1234567)
and trim(IBF_RONUMBER) = 'RO54321'

none of the other lines would end up in the executed SQL because the user left them empty on the prompt screen.

SO, I asked my DBAs - can you help me build indexes over this to optimize performance?  I asked them if they need actual usage statistics - they answered NO.  What they gave me was one big index over all the possible columns used in the search, as if someone filled in every possible field on the inquiry search screen.

They told me:
- It does not matter the ordering of the columns in the index
- The optimizer would do the rest

---

***Is this the proper way to go about this?!***   I have my doubts.

Sorry for the weird highlighting, first time poster and I have no clue why that did that!

Comment: Yes, your DBAs are idiots.

Answer (score 1):

Your DBAs are wrong, that single index is unlikely to be helpful!

You would be better off having indexes on each of the individual columns (but see note below), and generating the SQL for the query dynamically along these lines:

```
query := 'select ibf_unitnumber, ibf_locationnumber, ibf_repairingsubcenternum, 
ibf_repairingdistrictnum, ibf_customernumber, process_instance_id, 
ibf_repairdate, ibf_ronumber, ibf_customername, BF_WORKTYPE, 
ibf_districtnumber, status, ibf_jobtype,ibf_pmvalidationform_req, 
ibf_ecmform_req 
from FIELD_CT 
WHERE 1=1';

if customerNumber is not null then
   query := query || ' and IBF_CUSTOMERNUMBER=trim(:customerNumber)';
end if;
if customerName is not null then
... etc.
```

I have used PL/SQL syntax above, but I suspect you are using something else - but similar principles apply.  The key points are:

1. Only add the conditions you actually need to your query SQL.
2. Use **bind variables** for the actual values - do not concatenate them into the string.

Also, I deliberately moved the TRIM() functions on your conditions to the other side.  It makes sense to trim data typed in by the user to search, it does not make sense to trim the data already in the database because:

- Adding the trim() to the column means Oracle cannot use a simple index on that column, it would require a function-based index on TRIM(column)
- Data stored in the database should already be clean, it should not need trimming!

### NOTE

I said above put indexes on each column.  In fact you would not want an index for any columns that have a very low cardinality e.g. it is not normally worth putting an index on Gender which can only be male or female.

Answer (score 0):

Once I encountered the same problem, but with less amount of possible fields. As I and my colleagues found, there is no simple solution. We had made some experiments and chosen following:

- create some indexes. It was the most hard to choose columns for index. No one can choose it better than you, unfortunately.
- create pipelined function, which creates a dynamic SQL based only on fields, that was filled by user. Without of that, conditions like `where some_field = <some value> or <some_value> is null` lead to full scan of table. You don't need namely pipelined function, but you better use dynamic SQL here.
- Use hint `FIRST_ROWS(n)` to show first n records as fast as possible.

Also you can make some of fields obligatory and create index on that fields. It can help in some cases. For example, if your table contains dates of events and most of users works only with recent events.